# Nginx 301 Redirect http (naked and www) to https www, plus wildcard subdomain to https

Tags: redirect, nginx

I'm trying to set up an Nginx proxy server for a multi-tenant Saas with lots of custom domain names. What I want to do is create a server block that can handle the following requests, all as 301 permanent:

1. http://custom-domain.com to https://www.custom-domain.com (custom-domain.com could be any user-set domain name)
2. http://www.custom-domain.com to https://www.custom-domain.com (again, any domain name)
3. http://*.saas-domain.com to https://*.saas-domain.com (saas-domain,com is a single domain name for my service)

I am currently handling this with a few If statements, but it looks hacky and I am hoping for some help with a more efficient way:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;

    location / {

      # if 'www' redirect to https
      if ($host ~* ^(www)) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
      }
      # if '*.saas-domain.com' redirect to https://*.saas-domain.com
      if ($host ~* ^(.*)\.saas-domain\.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
      }
      # if not 'www' redirect to https and add 'www'
      if ($host !~* ^(www)) {
        return 301 https://www.$host$1 permanent;
      }
    }
}
```

Is this the best way to handle all of my scenarios? I think the complication is the wildcard custom domains. I'm concerned with the If statement's overhead. TIA!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nginx recommend not to use "If" statements unless you have no other way to solve your issue. I would suggest to add separate blocks for your domain names as this will give you more flexibility.

Try the following to see if it helps.

```
# Capture requests that already have www and redirect to https

server {

    listen 80;
    server_name www.*;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;

}

# Captures the saas-domain.com requests and redirects them

server {

    listen 80 ;
    server_name *.saas-domain.com;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;

}

# Default capture everything else and redirect to https://www.

server {

    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name _;
    return 301 https://www.$host$request_uri;

}
```

Test this first before implementing it in production.

[Nginx Server names](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html)

[Nginx if is evil](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/)

[Nginx variables](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_host)

Comment: Thanks for the tip on creating separate servers @markybb41! I took what you had and create a config that is working. The only changes I had to make to yours was to use the $host variable instead of $server_name for the first and second servers. I also didn't need to declare the server_name in the last server block; it caught everything I threw at it: